# Mailmessage.from not working as expected

Tags: c#, system.net.mail

thanks in advance for any help!

I want it so when A@gmail.com receives the email it appears to be coming from B@gmail.com. I believed this would work but it continues to appear to come from A@gmail.com. I've attempted to use ReplytoList/Headers but with no luck any help would be much appreciated.

```
using (var client = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("A@gmail.com", "$$$$$"),
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            })
            {
                var mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("A@gmail.com")); 
                mail.From = new MailAddress("B@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = String.Format("Request to Contact from {0}", form.CompanyName);
                mail.Body = form.Message;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mail);
                    retValue = "Your Request for Contact was submitted successfully. We will contact you shortly.";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to add the `B@gmail.com` in to your `A@gmail.com` account as an alternative email address, otherwise gmail smtp server won't let you spoof the email address.

[image]

Comment: So does that mean you could not send yourself an email from `noreply@gmail.com` unless it was listed as an alternate email address in your account? I do believe you are on the right track though, where Google is stopping the OP from spoofing an email to himself.

Comment: Thanks that could be it! Had my suspicions something like that was happening. Is there away round this as I'm passing in b@gmail.com from a contact form?

Comment: yes , this is the problem ,see the screen i update, and fix it. dont forget to reward me it helped :)

Comment: Sorry Meda, b@gmail.com could be any email address and unlikely to be my own as it's coming from a contact form.

Comment: Ok in this case, google will not be helpful , since they would consider it as spamming.